# SUM all columns of a specific data type rather than calling each column by name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to get the sum of all columns of a decimal type, grouped by the unique ID field.  Is there an easier way to sum all columns than by listing every column name?  Perhaps by data type since the columns all have an identical type (decimal(18,4))?

This is what I'm doing right now:

```
SUM(
ISNULL(TABLEA.aaa,0)+
ISNULL(TABLEB.bbb,0)+
ISNULL(TABLEC.ccc,0)+

) AS TOTAL
```

etc, ad infinitum

Comment: No there is not, if you dont use dynamic queries

Comment: And using dynamic queries is probably harder than what you're doing now, unless there are hundreds of columns.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't meant to be a dynamic SQL solution, but rather a time saver. Run this against a table you are interested in, copy the results back to your query window, and with a few mods like delete the last plus, get it working.

```
Select 'isnull(' + Column_Name + ',0)+'
From information_schema.columns
Where TABLE_NAME = 'myTable'
and data_type = 'int'
```

Comment: While it is a worthy suggestion, I'm not sure it answers the question. still got my upvote.

Comment: Actually the question was about decimal(18,4). This is what I mean, it is dynamic qyery. Try to use stuff, for xml statement and you will get ready to use statement, but it it dynamic query

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri then change the query to be data_type= 'decimal' and numeric_precision=18 and numeric_scale=4. Again, the above answer is meant to be a helper to generate your SQL string instead of typing out a bunch of column names.